# How to start "Shape collage" application from terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I just installed application "[shape collage](http://www.shapecollage.com/)" on my Archlinux, but I don't know how to start it via the terminal. Command `shape-collage` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: use `pacman` to find where it installed binaries.

Comment: I found an anwser. If we want to execute the program we have to execute `/opt/shape-collage/shape-collage` in the terminal as program is installed in folder `/opt`.

Comment: @Gilles How do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `shape-collage` is installed in `/opt` directory which is not included in your `PATH`. Because of this you have to use the absolute path of the application when you start it from terminal:

```
/opt/shape-collage/shape-collage
```

If you want to get rid by the absolute path and use only `shape-collage` to start it, you must to add `/opt/shape-collage` directory to your `PATH` as follow:

```
PATH="/opt/shape-collage:$PATH"
```

To make the change permanently, add the above line in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: ...unless you're using something other than `bash`.

Comment: @strugee Yes, ...unless.